# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 Texture setting does not seem to work

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, texture2d

I have this problem with an older device that has an android version I still like to support (2.3.5) where the texture sometimes works.

I have 5 textures loaded in memory from the start of the game (does not change and is not reloaded). Everything shows up fine in the tutorial but in the game it does not. The rendering process and object loading are exactly the same and they work perfectly on my newer device (Nexus 4) for all game modes and tutorial.

I load 4 texture of 1024x1024 and 1 texture of 512x512. The textures that are not working properly are the last loaded and bound textures. So it could be a memory issue, but how can I find this out? The OpenGL error function does not show any error during gameplay, even though the textures are not shown correctly.

- Both devices support OpenGL ES 2.0.
- The third and fourth textures do work in the tutorial part of the game, so the device is able to load at least the first four textures, which should indicate it is not the amount of textures being the problem.
- The old device supports 1024x1024 textures according to the specs.
- Changing all the textures to 512x512 shows the same issue, which should have worked if memory was an issue because you can hold 4 of those textures in 1 1024x1024 texture which already works perfect on all devices. (1x512 and 1x1024 memory space equals 5x512 space)
- It works perfectly on the Nexus 4 so a coding error is unlikely.
- OpenGL does not provide me with an error of some sort using the openglerror function call in the loading/setting up/rendering calls so that should mean all OpenGL stuff is fine.
- The loading of my texturepool, the creation and loading of the objects (pool), the render function (including the shader) is in all modes exactly the same code so that does not effect the difference. I have debugged all the objects rendered with OpenGL to see if some data is corrupt or incorrect but it all is correct when I pass it to the render pipeline. This code is passing the integer '3' to the shader in the rendering code as texture id. The texture loaded at '3' should be the one I need, but somewhere in OpenGL it decides to use texture '1' and not higher at those moments, but in the tutorial it puts the same data to OpenGL but then OpenGL decides to use the '3' texture ID as passed and intended...

posting code is an issue due to the complexity of the engine which handles all loading/rendering etc. of the graphics part of the game. Posting all code of my game/engine seems a little bit overkill :s so if some part is needed for solving this issue I will post it.

I am basically out of ideas to try and solve this issue :( does anyone has any idea or suggestion to what I can try, or maybe a solution?

Comment: This is your problem, you do not understand how sampler uniforms work in GLSL. You do not pass texture IDs, you pass texture ***unit*** IDs, and they sample whatever texture is bound to that unit.

Comment: I do understand how sampler uniforms work, it works perfectly fine on almost all devices (including emulator with different android versions), I have only forgotten to put in the word 'unit' in my text but I thought it was clear enough. It is also not my first OpenGL ES 2 game. I bound them to the textures GL_TEXTURE0 to GL_TEXTURE4. The thing is that somehow without errors the games acts that way on that device (afaik) only and only for that part of the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this (and appearently also my other posted) problem, it was a bug in the driver software of the GPU, the textureunit id was only taking once, more info: http://androidblog.reindustries.com/hack-bad-gpu-fix-not-using-correct-texture-opengl/